# Flutter: How to get app path from within the app after it's built

Tags: flutter-linux

I have a project named `foo`.
I built the bundle by `flutter build linux` and the binary is available in `/build/linux/x64/release/bundle/foo`
Lets say I moved this bundle folder to ~/Downloads and then execute `foo`
I should be able to display the path of the binary `/home/user/Downloads/bundle/foo`.
If I rename `foo` to `bar` manually and execute `bar`, I should be able to display `/home/user/Downloads/bundle/bar`

`Directory.current` will give the parent directory (`/home/user/Downloads/bundle/`), but I need the name of the binary too (`foo`). Is this possible?